# C: convert a real number to 64 bit floating point binary

Tags: c, floating-point, binary, converters, fractions

I'm trying to write a code that converts a real number to a 64 bit floating point binary. In order to do this, the user inputs a real number (for example, 547.4242) and the program must output a 64 bit floating point binary.

My ideas:

- The sign part is easy.
- The program converts the integer part (547 for the previous example) and stores the result in an int variable. Then, the program converts the fractional part (.4242 for the previous example) and stores the result into an array (each position of the array stores '1' or '0').

This is where I'm stuck. Summarizing, I have:   "Integer part = 1000100011" (type int) and "Fractional part = 0110110010011000010111110000011011110110100101000100" (array).

How can I proceed?

Comment: you say you store it as a double, but it looks like binary... not sure what you're asking really

Comment: double x = (double) y; ?

Comment: @Noctis I'm sorry, I meant an int variable.

Comment: It's easy to get this almost right but if I recall correctly there is quite a lot of work involved in getting the conversion absolutely right.

Comment: A typical 64 bit floating point binary could have a value like "100... (300 zeros) 00.0".  Converting the integer portion of that real number into a `int`, `long`, `long long`, etc. will certainly result in truncation.  The "integer portion of the real number" --> `int` approach your idea proposes is far to limiting.  Suggest 1) another approach 2) and post your code.

Comment: Since you are converting a 'real' number (floating point) to a 64bit floating point,  You need to learn the actual bit-wise representation of both the 32bit floating point and the 64bit floating point. As a hint, 1bit sign, Xbits normalized value, Ybits mantisa.  Note the mantisa is not +/- from zero, but the mid point of the max mantisa value

Answer (score 0):

the following code is used to determine internal representation of a floating point  number according to the IEEE754 notation. This code is made in Turbo c++ ide but you can easily convert for a generalised ide.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void decimal_to_binary(unsigned char);

union u
{
    float f;
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    char*ptr;
    union u a;

    clrscr();
    printf("ENTER THE FLOATING POINT NUMBER : \n");
    scanf("%f",&a.f);

    ptr=&a.c+sizeof(float);

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(float);i++)
    {
        ptr--;
        decimal_to_binary(*ptr);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void decimal_to_binary(unsigned char n)
{
    int arr[8];
    int i;
    //printf("n = %u  ",n);

    for(i=7;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(n%2==0)
            arr[i]=0;
        else
            arr[i]=1;
        n/=2;
    }

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    printf(" ");
}
```

For further details visit Click [here](http://codingloverlavi.blogspot.in/2013/08/internal-representation-of-floating.html)!

Comment: Somehow it seems to me that that does the opposite of what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis you are right. I want to do the oposite.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to treat the value as an integer, so read your `547.4242` as an unsigned long long (ie 64-bits or more), ie `5474242`, counting the number of digits after the '.', in this case 4.  Now you have a value which is 10^4 bigger than it should be.  So you float the `5474242` (as a double, or long double) and divide by 10^4.

Decimal to binary conversion is deceptively simple.  When you have more bits than the float will hold, then it will have to round.  More fun occurs when you have more digits than a 64-bit integer will hold -- noting that trailing zeros are special -- and you have to decide whether to round or not (and what rounding occurs when you float).  Then there's dealing with an E+/-99.  Then when you do the eventual division (or multiplication) by 10^n, you have (a) another potential rounding, and (b) the issue that large 10^n are not *exactly* represented in your floating point -- which is another source of error.  (And for E+/-99 forms, you may need upto and a little beyond 10^300 for the final step.)

Enjoy !

Comment: If I input 547.4242 and read it as an int I loose the fractional part (0.4242), right?

Comment: He means that you omit the decimal point `'.'` and then read the number `547.4242` as integer, i.e. as `5474242`, while remembering how many digits follow the decimal point. Then you divide the integer by 10^x, where x is the number of decimal places. Be sure to do a floating point division.

Comment: The other way of looking at this is that you move the decimal point to the right.  For each digit you move the decimal point past, you are, of course, multiplying the number by 10.  So when you have the complete number, you convert it to a suitable floating point format, and then divide it by the power of ten required to restore its true value.  (You could take the first digit after the decimal point, divide by 10 and add it to the whole number part, then the next digit, divide by 100, add it in, and so on.  But every one of those operations would add another rounding error!)

Answer (score 0):

In order to correctly round all possible decimal representations to the nearest `double`, you need big integers. Using only the basic integer types from C will leave you to re-implement big integer arithmetics. Each of these two approaches is possible, more information about each follows:

1. For the first approach, you need a big integer library: [GMP](http://www.exploringbinary.com/correct-decimal-to-floating-point-using-big-integers/) is a good one. Armed with such a big integer library, you tackle an input such as the example 123.456E78 as the integer 123456 * 10<sup>75</sup> and start wondering what values M in [2<sup>53</sup> … 2<sup>54</sup>) and P in [-1022 … 1023] make (M / 2<sup>53</sup>) * 2<sup>P</sup> closest to this number. This question can be answered with big integer operations, following the steps described in [this blog post](http://www.exploringbinary.com/correct-decimal-to-floating-point-using-big-integers/) (summary: first determine P. Then use a division to compute M). A complete implementation must take care of subnormal numbers and infinities (`inf` is the correct result to return for any decimal representation of a number that would have an exponent larger than +1023).
2. The second approach, if you do not want to include or implement a full general-purpose big integer library, still requires a few basic operations to be implemented on arrays of C integers representing large numbers. The function `decfloat()` in this [implementation](http://git.etalabs.net/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/floatscan.c) represents large numbers in base 10<sup>9</sup> because that simplifies the conversion from the initial decimal representation to the internal representation as an array `x` of `uint32_t`.

Comment: I don't think that most `atof()` implementations use some kind of BigInteger or BigDecimal, internally. ISTM that OP's "real" is a string, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Could you cite one implementation of `atof` in a reputable library that does not use big integers to parse `1.0E300`? Most libraries use David M. Gay's code, here is a write-up about Glibc's implementation: http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/ , and I already linked to Musl's. These are already a majority, depending how you count, but I am interested in the subject and I would like to see **one** implementation without some sort of big integers (that works. I am not interested if it produces results within ten ULPs of the correct result).

Comment: What is reputable and what is not? I very much doubt that most `atof` implementations use big integers.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Okay, please cite one `atof` implementation that does not have some sort of big integer implementation from **any** libc.

Comment: I don't use Unix, I have no implemenation of libc here. I do know that many languages can do this without even having a big integer implementation around.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It is possible to implement special-purpose bigint operations that only solve this problem without linking to a complete bigint implementation. This is what (I hoped that) my answer shows Musl is doing. Let us continue this discussion when you have an example of `atof` implementation to propose, otherwise it is just going to be “—I think… —I don't think…” and that can last for a long time.

Comment: Ok, it may be that some things are solved with a minimal big integer array, but, without knowing the libc implementations, I feel it can be much simpler.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Then please show how you convert 1.23456789123E300 to the nearest `double` (this is the accuracy recommended by the C standard, e.g. C99 7.20.1.3:9, since `1.23456789123E300` has fewer than DECIMAL_DIG significant digits).

Comment: I don't know how I would do it. I do know that many languages manage it (and properly) without big integers.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No, you **think** that many languages manage it properly without big integers, because you haven't looked, and because it seems simpler than it really is. I can only recommend the blog I have linked to several time in this question and these comments, http://www.exploringbinary.com/ , if you are interested in seeing how it really works. I have provided the link to the post that explain Glibc's implementation and a straight link to the Musl implementation. Others use David M. Gay's code, described originally in http://www.ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf (and explained in the blog).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that many languages manage it properly without big integers.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Python? Java? PHP?

Comment: I just looked at your links. They use 160-192 bit integers. If that is what you mean with big integers, then I agree. But for me, big integers are much larger.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Is your quote of “160-192 bit” from the latest article in the blog, http://www.exploringbinary.com/gcc-avoids-double-rounding-errors-with-round-to-odd/ ? I am afraid that this has nothing to do with that. 160-192 is the **intermediate precision** at which GCC rounds floating-point constants using rounding-to-odd, before rounding them to the target precision. But how does GCC arrive to these 160-192 bits, I hear you ask. It uses a multi-precision library, MPFR: http://www.exploringbinary.com/real-c-rounding-is-perfect-gcc-now-converts-correctly/

Comment: Yes, GCC seems to do that. Others don't.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I, and the authors of GCC, Java, PHP, Python, Glibc, Musl, would be very interested in knowing how “others” manage this feat, so if you ever find a reference of one “other” that doesn't, feel free to share.

Comment: So some do it that way. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a basic conversion.  Enough to get OP started.

OP's "integer part of real number" --> `int` is far too limiting.  Better to simply convert the entire string to a large integer like `uintmax_t`.  Note the decimal point `'.'` and account for overflow while scanning.

This code does not handle exponents nor negative numbers.  It may be off in the the last bit or so due to limited integer `ui` or the the final `num = ui * pow10(expo)`.  It handles most overflow cases.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

double my_atof(const char *src) {
  uintmax_t ui = 0;
  int dp = '.';
  size_t dpi;
  size_t i = 0;
  size_t toobig = 0;
  int ch;
  for (i = 0; (ch = (unsigned char) src[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
    if (ch == dp) {
      dp = '\0';  // only get 1 dp
      dpi = i;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isdigit(ch)) {
      break; // illegal character
    }
    ch -= '0';
    // detect overflow
    if (toobig || 
        (ui >= UINTMAX_MAX / 10 && 
        (ui > UINTMAX_MAX / 10 || ch > UINTMAX_MAX % 10))) {
      toobig++;
      continue;
    }
    ui = ui * 10 + ch;
  }
  intmax_t expo = toobig;
  if (dp == '\0') {
    expo -= i - dpi - 1;
  }

  double num;
  if (expo < 0) {
    // slightly more precise than: num = ui * pow10(expo);
    num = ui / pow10(-expo);
  } else {
    num = ui * pow10(expo);
  }
  return num;
}
```